# JQuery iterating through textboxes and changing its color

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to iterate through all the empty textboxes in a table and change its background colour.  I'm using the following JQuery code:

```
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
            var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
            emptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
            this.css('background-color', '#ffff00');
//            $('#Col3Txtbx').css('background-color', '#ffff00');    
            });
        });
```

`This` does not seem to refer to the textbox which seems strange to me.  When I uncomment out the particular textbox, it does reset the background colour.

Can someone explain to me what 'This' is referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback), the callback to each will be passed an index and the element in question and this will be set to the domElement.  So, change   `this.css('background-color', '#ffff00')` to  `$(this).css('background-color', '#ffff00');`

Answer (score 3):

The each function works a little differently:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
  var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
  emptyTextBoxes.each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).css('background-color', '#ffff00');
  });
});
```

But you can make this work without each() as well:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
  var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
  emptyTextBoxes.css('background-color', '#ffff00');
});
```

Even shorter version:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
  $("input:text[value='']").css('background-color', '#ffff00');
});
```

Edit: as "rz" pointed out, you can still use the `this` keyword, but you'll have to wrap the element into a jQuery object:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
  var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
  emptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ffff00');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

the this that is changing the color is referring to the button. If you move this where you return this.value it might work.